# How to render facebook image link on my website?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I was wondering if it was possible to convert the link facebook provides into an image.
Let's say I have this link https://instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/211923633_341835957436071_2595781851662408146_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=upj99hCjROUAX93eUge&edm=ABZsPhsBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=bc90a021d242b91c19fbfb074876837e&oe=60EDD8F5&_nc_sid=4efc9f (a picture of a hedgehog). How would I convert it to an image so that a static page can use it?
`src="<link>"` deosn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to web dev, too. I tried to figure this out, but the best I could do was to copy the full  HTML by using Inspect in Chrome. That gets you this, which doesn't work, even though it's basically the only HTML on the page:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;" src="https://instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/211923633_341835957436071_2595781851662408146_n.jpg?tp=1&amp;_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=103&amp;_nc_ohc=upj99hCjROUAX93eUge&amp;edm=ABZsPhsBAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=bc90a021d242b91c19fbfb074876837e&amp;oe=60EDD8F5&amp;_nc_sid=4efc9f" width="454" height="454">
```

Isolating just the image link (https://instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/211923633_341835957436071_2595781851662408146_n.jpg) doesn't work, either.

I think maybe Facebook/Instagram are using some kind of special link that can't be shared outside the platform. My workaround would be to download the image and upload it to a free image hosting website and link to that.

Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't work for me, thanks for the help anyways. They're keeping a base64 version of the image in that file the links point to. If only I knew how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Image as a Link</h2>

<p>The image below is a link. Try to click on it.</p>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295069/how-to-render-facebook-image-link-on-my-website/68295245?noredirect=1#comment120701892_68295245"><img src="https://instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/211923633_341835957436071_2595781851662408146_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fbeg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=upj99hCjROUAX93eUge&edm=ABZsPhsBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=bc90a021d242b91c19fbfb074876837e&oe=60EDD8F5&_nc_sid=4efc9f.jpg" alt="picofahedgehog" style="width:42px;height:42px;"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this......!

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to keep the images on their servers, so saving them by hand as you've suggested isn't an option.