# Display image(which is in url form and doesn't end with jpg or png) in html or react(JSX)

Tags: html, reactjs

How to display image URL which is not in jpg or png format in HTML?

for example:
https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/273727367_1005857900021092_3491035421001286622_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=cIHsUcR6vjMAX-tyRC8&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT-h1KbjT1bON-nXzCsQr-xWjKNenRQ5gzwCb5PrlGVuHg&oe=6212A471&_nc_sid=498da5

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295069/how-to-render-facebook-image-link-on-my-website

Comment: That didn't resolve the issue.